# Readingdata from two tables using Unique ID's

Tags: c#

I am try retrieve some data from 2 database tables namely AnswersTable and QuestionsTable in my c# project.the AnswerTtable contains  columns called "QuestionID"and "UserId" I am trying to query every single question that was attempted by the user using the UserID and QuestionID. If the user attempted 10 questions and each question has a unique ID how will I able to query the all the questions attempted by the user using the  QuestionID.
This is how I am retrieving the questionId from the AnswersTable

```
String questionid;
Query = "SELECT * FROM AnswersTable WHERE UserId = '1'";
           theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
           while (theReader.Read())
           {


               questionid = theReader["QuestionId"].ToString();

           }
```

After I retrieve or read the questionID I pass it on to the next query:

```
Query = "SELECT *  FROM QuestionsTable WHERE Id = '" + questionid + "'";
            theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
            while(theReader.Read())
            {

              // I know I meant to do something in here in order to retrieve all the 10 attempted 
               //questions using their Unique IDs, how do I retrieve each and every question using 
               // the questionIDs?

            }
```

I hope this makes sense , Thank you

Comment: What kind of database are you using, and what data type is `UserId`? Also, an example of what you are trying to get would be helpful.

Comment: I am using sql database, UserId datatype is int... I am trying to get the questions attempted by the user using the questionID.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all questions and their answers by a particular user (in this case user id = 1) using following query by joining the two tables. In this way you don't need to have two data readers. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT A.AnswerId      
      ,A.UserID
       ,A.QuestionId
      ,Q.Question
      ,A.Answer
FROM AnswersTable A
    INNER JOIN QuestionsTable Q ON Q.QuestionId = A.QuestionId
WHERE UserID = 1
```